# Failed to register AppImage in system via libappimage - how to fix?

Tags: 18.04, launcher, appimage

I have just installed AppImageLauncher on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with MATE using [this official deb-package](https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher/releases/download/v2.2.0/appimagelauncher_2.2.0-travis995.0f91801.bionic_amd64.deb).

Then I set it up using `AppImageLauncherSettings` - set *Location where to store your AppImage files to ease their management* to `~/Software/AppImages`.

Then I have downloaded CubicSDR [AppImage-file](https://github.com/cjcliffe/CubicSDR/releases/download/0.2.5/CubicSDR-0.2.5-x86_64.AppImage) to my `~/Downloads` folder and double clicked it in the Caja. Then window named *Desktop Integration — AppImageLauncher* was opened, and I clicked *Integrate and run* button in it.

Then I get the following window:

> [image: Error — AppImageLauncher]
> Error — AppImageLauncher
> Failed to register AppImage in system via libappimage

What does this mean? How should I fix this?

Note that already downloaded AppImage files are well integrated and I see them in MATE menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be exclusive problem of only CubicSDR AppImage.

Three other AppImages like

- App.Outlet-2.0.0-beta-1.AppImage
- drawio-x86_64-14.6.13_fed376c2692af2074327a4f8fb9ccdf9.AppImage
- ubports-installer_0.8.8-beta_linux_x86_64.AppImage
- vnote-linux-x64.AppImage

are well integrated.

So I create a symlink between CubicSDR and my Desktop folder by

```
chmod +x ~/Software/AppImages/CubicSDR-0.2.5-x86_64.AppImage
ln -s ~/Software/AppImages/CubicSDR-0.2.5-x86_64.AppImage ~/Desktop/CubicSDR
```

and have reported [issue](https://github.com/cjcliffe/CubicSDR/issues/908) to CubicSDR.